# Laravel error: Call to a member function first() on string when using Resource::collection

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm creating an backend with multiple stores. Each stores with their own products

I've created a store and a product and am trying to resource the products to all the stores.

When I try add my products to my store in `StoreResource.php`

using:

```
'products' => ProductResource::collection($this->products),
```

I get the error:

> Call to a member function first() on string

I've looked on line for numerous explanations and tutorials, but get met with the same error

*** STORE MODEL ***

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

***STORE CONTROLLER ***

```
public function index()
{
    return StoreResource::collection(Store::with('products')->paginate(5));
}
```

***STORE Resource***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class StoreResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'name' => $this->name,
         'description' => $this->description,
         'image' => $this->image,
         'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
         'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
         'products' => ProductResource::collection($this->products),
       ];
    }
}
```

*** Product MODEL ***

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
}
```

***Product CONTROLLER ***

```
public function index()
{
    return ProductResource::collection(Product::with('stores')->paginate(5));
}
```

***Product Resource***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;


use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Purchaseresource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
      return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'productName' => $this->productName,
        'amount' => $this->amount,
        'total_product_price' => $this->total_product_price,
        'week' => $this->week,
        'day' => $this->day,
        'month' => $this->month,
        'year' => $this->year,
        'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
      ];
   }
}
```

What I expect is to get a relation between my store and products so they are displayed as this in the API repsonse

```
 {
    "id": 0, 
    "name": "Store", 
    "image": "image",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "product",
            "price": 7,
            "qty": 100,
            "total": 0
        },
     ]    
}
```

So the product would become nested in the store.

Comment: In which line and file the error is thrown?

Comment: I just figured it out, needed to remove products from the store model , controller and etc and just use `'product' => $this->product,`

Answer (score 0):

you first need to make a query in your controller like:

```
$query = Store::all();
```

and after something like:

```
$stores = StoreResource::collection($query);
```

and in your Resource you can pass:

```
'product' => $this->product
```

in the resource array